# Are there Linear Programming libraries with the Simplex algorithm for Clojure?

Tags: algorithm, clojure

The Stigler Diet problem is a Linear Programming problem.  It takes a list of foods and their nutritional values and solves for an optimized selection and quantities that meet objectives and constraints.  Are there clojure libraries for Linear Programming - Simplex Algorithm, other than levand/prolin to work this?

Comment: http://www.joptimizer.com

Comment: Try Sage (http://www.sagemath.org) or Lindo http://www.lindo.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java [JaCoP](http://jacop.osolpro.com/) constraint programming library implements among others the Simplex algorithm. For Clojure, there's the [CloCoP](https://github.com/aengelberg/clocop) clojure wrapper over JaCoP.

Clojure's core.logic also has options for [constraint programming](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic/wiki/Features#clpfd).

Comment: Thank you!  That was a great resource.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a clojure library: [prolin](https://github.com/levand/prolin) uses the Simplex implementation provided by [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/). It's probably the most idiomatic api in clojure for linear programming. Current version in github uses org.apache.commons.math3 v3.2, however according to this [JIRA entry](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MATH-1079) the simplex implementation has significantly been improved in v3.3, so it may be worth upgrading (see [prolin issue #1](https://github.com/levand/prolin/issues/1)).

Also of interest is the Java Constraint Programming API ([JSR 331](http://jsr331.org/)). There's [a clojure project using that API](https://github.com/maxtuno/Clojure---JSR-331---Puzzles). Although its name hints towards constraint programming (CP), [this blog post talks about using it for accessing linear programming (LP) solvers](http://cpstandard.wordpress.com/2012/07/26/six-new-jsr-331-implementations-with-linear-solvers/) such as GLPK, lp_solve, gurobi, etc.